# Webpack resolve alias with query params

Tags: webpack

Using webpack to build my application I am having trouble using `resolveLoader` config to work with query params. To be specific I am using the [bundle-loader](https://github.com/webpack/bundle-loader) but wish to use my own custom loader instead and want to avoid modifying the app code.

App.js

```
require('bundle?lazy&name=nameOfChunk!location/of/file');
```

Webpack config:

```
resolveLoader: {
    alias: {
        'bundle': 'location/of/new/loader/i/wish/to/use/instead'
    }
}
```

The above works but the query params are ignored. Does anyone have a solution for this so I can avoid having to do this in my app:

```
require('location/of/new/loader/i/wish/to/use/instead?lazy&name=nameOfChunk!location/of/file');
```

Comment: Yes, this is [known bug](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1289) of webpack. Now it is fixed in pull request, but still not merged. So let's wait and pray.